# page background color for Part

Tags: color, backgrounds

I want to set the background color specifically for the page created for each "Part" section in my document (e.g. Part I xxx, Part II xxxx). I am using the book document class. Solutions for setting (and resetting) the background colour were not able to specifically color the page with Part I xxxx on it, but also coloured the page after that.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

First page

\cleardoublepage
\pagecolor{green}
\part{Example for pagecolor}
\pagecolor{white}

Last page
\end{document}
```

The "Part" page and the page following it are *both* colored green.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5):

You can patch the `part` command to add the page color instead of adding it manually. But since a `newpage` is issued at the end of `\part` internally (when `openright` option is used (default)) the page color is applied  to the next page also. This can be avoided by patching the `\@endpart` command. You can do it the hard way or the smart way as shown in the following code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
%%-----------------Hard coding----------------------
%\renewcommand\part{%
%  \if@openright
%    \cleardoublepage
%  \else
%    \clearpage
%  \fi
%  \pagecolor{green}   %% Added line here
%  \thispagestyle{plain}%
%  \if@twocolumn
%    \onecolumn
%    \@tempswatrue
%  \else
%    \@tempswafalse
%  \fi
%  \null\vfil
%  \secdef\@part\@spart}

%\renewcommand\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
%                \pagecolor{white}   %%% Added line here
%              \if@twoside
%               \if@openright
%                \null
%                \thispagestyle{empty}%
%                \newpage
%               \fi
%              \fi
%              \if@tempswa
%                \twocolumn
%              \fi}
%%--------- end of hard coding ---------------------

%%---smart coding ----------------------------------
\usepackage{xpatch}
%
\xpatchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}
      {\pagecolor{green}\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@endpart}{\vfil\newpage}{\vfil\newpage
              \pagecolor{white}}{}{}
%%--------- end of smart coding ---------------------
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
First page

\cleardoublepage
\part{Example for pagecolor}

Last page
\end{document}
```

[image]